# Retrieve images from a link

Tags: php, image, url

Is there a script or service or snippet or method or anything that can get thumbnail from a url, by thumbnail i dont mean snapshot of the site, but an image that can automatically be fetched and used as post thumbnail, much like the one used in facebook. The image should be fetched thus img src="xxxxxxx?url=google.com" . this would fetch the google logo

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are existing solutions for this, but it's not really hard to implement:

1. you need to fetch the remote site, for e.g. with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
2. optionally use [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to clean up the source HTML
3. parse the output with an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) if you used Tidy to clean the fetched data, or an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
4. fetch the first `n` images from the site (`n` should be a relatively small number)
5. store this fetched image set in a cache because this fetching, parsing thing could take time

Comments:

- you may fetch the `robots.txt` from the site to check whether it's allowed to use/index the content
- set a timeout for this remote website fetching, because if the website is down or slow it would timeout on your site as well
- limit the concurrent fetching to a site and globally to protect against DoS-ing
- you could use an HTTP client and limit the fetched HTML data size, or use `HEAD` HTTP method to fetch the `Content-Length` before downloading the actual content if it's allowed

Comment: Don't use file_get_contents for a remote site, use CUrl or fsocket.

Comment: Yes I did, I liked your answer, I was just simply letting him know not to use file_get_contents and to use an http client like what you said.... file_get_contents() is lazily used by people who are learning php, and its really bad to use for remote files. Great answer! It's what I was going to write myself.

Comment: Sorry than, I got a downvote the same time, and I tought it was connected w/ your comment.